# How to format x-axis time scale values in Chart.js v2

Tags: chart.js

I am able to format the tooltips when I hover over a datapoint on a line chart via `options.scales.xAxes.time.tooltipFormat`, but I can't seem to do it for the x-axis tick lables. My `data.labels` is an array of moment objects. They display as `"MMM DD, YYYY"` (e.g. Feb 23, 2012), but I want to drop the year.

Comment: See this codepen https://codepen.io/shivabhusal/pen/ayyVeL?editors=1010

Answer (score 113):

Just set all the selected time unit's `displayFormat` to `MMM DD`

```
options: {
  scales: {
    xAxes: [{
      type: 'time',
      time: {
        displayFormats: {
           'millisecond': 'MMM DD',
           'second': 'MMM DD',
           'minute': 'MMM DD',
           'hour': 'MMM DD',
           'day': 'MMM DD',
           'week': 'MMM DD',
           'month': 'MMM DD',
           'quarter': 'MMM DD',
           'year': 'MMM DD',
        }
        ...
```

Notice that I've set all the unit's display format to `MMM DD`. A better way, if you have control over the range of your data and the chart size, would be force a unit, like so

```
options: {
  scales: {
    xAxes: [{
      type: 'time',
      time: {
        unit: 'day',
        unitStepSize: 1,
        displayFormats: {
           'day': 'MMM DD'
        }
        ...
```

---

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/prfd1m8q/

Comment: I believe in your second code snippet, the `unit` and `unitStepSize` should be enclosed within the `time` object. [Updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/prfd1m8q/1125/). I tried making an edit but it was rejected as it deviated from your original intent of the post...

Comment: Thanks @tchan! Corrected.

Comment: Any idea how to translate date (months) into a different language other than english?

Comment: if the var is a string (for example `'2021-03-10'`) instead of a readily manageable object like a `moment` time object, you would better tell `jschart` how to parse that string by adding `parser: 'YYYY-MM-DD'` to the `time` method. In total the scripts look like type: 'time',
                  time: {
                        parser: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
                        unit: 'day',
                        unitStepSize: 1,
                        displayFormats: {'day': 'MMM DD',}
                    }

Answer (score 27):

as per the Chart js documentation page [tick configuration section](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/styling.html#tick-configuration). you can format the value of each tick using the callback function. for example I wanted to change locale of displayed dates to be always German. in the ticks parts of the axis options

```
ticks: {
    callback: function(value) { 
        return new Date(value).toLocaleDateString('de-DE', {month:'short', year:'numeric'}); 
    },
},
```

Comment: I think there's an issue for IE11 with that solution, it displays all dates as 'Invalid Date' where Chrome and Firefox works fine.

Comment: **Edit :** It seems it was the `new Date`that wasn't working actually, as I was doing it on a string such as `Feb 2017`. And IE doesn't seem to enjoy that much.

Answer (score 2):

I had a different use case,  I want different formats based how long between start and end time of data in graph.  I found this to be simplest approach

```js
let xAxes = {
    type: "time",
    time: {
        displayFormats: {
            hour: "hA"
        }
    },
    display: true,
    ticks: {
        reverse: true
    },
    gridLines: { display: false }
}
// if more than two days between start and end of data,  set format to show date,  not hrs
if ((parseInt(Cookies.get("epoch_max")) - parseInt(Cookies.get("epoch_min"))) > (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 2)) {
    xAxes.time.displayFormats.hour = "MMM D";
}
```

Comment: hello @Rob Raymond! Can you take a look at my question too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62086503/how-to-format-x-axis-based-on-how-long-between-start-and-end-time-of-data-in-cha . I have similiar problem, but can't work on it

Answer (score 0):

You could format the dates before you add them to your array. That is how I did. I used AngularJS

```js
//convert the date to a standard format
var dt = new Date(date);
//take only the date and month and push them to your label array

$rootScope.charts.mainChart.labels.push(dt.getDate() + "-" + (dt.getMonth() + 1));
```

Use this array in your chart presentation