# Chart.js showing time (HH:MM:SS - 24 hour clock) on xAxis

Tags: javascript, datetime, time, chart.js, axis-labels

I have a .Net Core application in which I am drawing a graph showing values for some measurements during the time of the day.

My "time" object is in Unix time, with milliseconds (e.g. 1502258405000). I have managed to convert it to a time object manually as follows:

```
var datetimes = $.map(data, function (value, index) {
    var datetime = new Date(value.timestamp);
    var iso = datetime.toISOString().match(/(\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2})T(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})/);
    return iso[2]; //Returns HH:MM:SS
});
```

However with this conversion my chart.js chart doesn't understand the time objects as time, which means (if there is a gap in the measurements) it won't show (and there is), as it will just put the measurements next to each other and handle them as strings.

I am not interested in showing the date as the data always will be collected within a known date. I changed my above implementation to:

```
var datetimes = $.map(gpsData, function (value, index) {
    return new Date(value.timestamp);
});
```

[image]

However when I plot this on my chart.js line chart it makes my chart show AM/PM values which is not desired, as seen here above. I want to have a 24 hour clock. I used the chart.js time value for the `xAxis` as seen here below to plot the values as seen in the picture above:

```
options: {
    scales: {
        xAxes: [{
            type: 'time',
            time: {
                format: "HH:MM:SS",
                min: minTime, //calculated above in my implementation
                max: maxTime  //same as above
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

However the values are not formatted as my desired output. So I was wondering what the proper way of adding **time of day** to the x axis on my graph using chart.js is or even how to format it my desired values?

Comment: have you try this solution to format your date?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37061945/how-to-format-x-axis-time-scale-values-in-chart-js-v2

Comment: Yup. And all combinations I can think of combined with that solution. The problem seems to be the fact that Chart.js doesn't support 24  hour clock after lots of hours of research. I have been unable to find anything in their docs that says otherwise.

Comment: could you provide me a jsfiddle? maybe you have to write the xAxis manually

Comment: I will get right onto doing so.

Comment: or maybe you can try this to custom your xAxis with ticks function, I just make a simple change from other ppl's Demo, good luck. 
http://jsfiddle.net/prfd1m8q/999/

Comment: Yeah. I have tried this, but as my "times" are in unix time when they come in I seem to get some problems as soon as I input them anywhere.
I have changed the example you shared and here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/prfd1m8q/1000/ Normally my unix times come in in MS, so I have removed the last three zeros from the values in the example.

Comment: @Anami Even using moment.js and it's unix implementation doesn't do anything for me. http://jsfiddle.net/prfd1m8q/1001/

Comment: @Anami I've managed to get the example you shared to work with my data, however it doesn't use the `type: 'time'` functionality of chart.js, and therefore I can't use it. I have a gap in my data that is not visualized without the `time` implementation. http://jsfiddle.net/prfd1m8q/1004/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that this wasn't possible for Chart.js so I moved to Highcharts.js instead, which supports this functionality.

Here below is my code for the solution:

```
function tripSpeedsLineGraph() {
    var gpsData = @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(Model.gpsData));

    chartData = []
    var reqData = $.map(gpsData, function (value, index) {
         chartData.push([new Date(value.timestamp), value.sp]);
    });

    var chart = Highcharts.chart('tripSpeedsLineChart', {
        chart: {
            type: 'spline',
            zoomType: 'x',
            panning: true,
            panKey: 'shift'
        },
        title: {
            text: "Speed during trip"
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Click and drag to zoom in. Hold down shift key to pan.'
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            dateTimeLabelFormats: {
                day: '%b %H:%M:%S'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Time of day'
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Speed'
            },
            min: 0
        },
        tooltip: {
            crosshairs: [true],
            formatter: function () {
                return "Datetime: " + moment.utc(moment.unix(this.x/1000)).format("DD/MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss") + "<br> Speed: " + this.y;
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Speed Data',
            data: chartData
        }]
    });
}
```

And the final result looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 12):

Actually this is supported (at least in recent versions of chartjs).

It seems like you have to specify the format for all the different formats that chartjs can display.

Check:
https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html#display-formats

In my project the following works for me:

```
 xAxes: [{
    type: 'time',
    time: {
        parser: timeFormat,
        // round: 'day'                                                                                                                                                                            
        tooltipFormat: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm',
        displayFormats: {
            millisecond: 'HH:mm:ss.SSS',
            second: 'HH:mm:ss',
            minute: 'HH:mm',
            hour: 'HH'
        }
    },
    display: true,
    scaleLabel: {
        display: true,
        labelString: 'Time'
    }
 }],
```

Answer (score 4):

Using Chart.js v2.9.4, for me this worked:

```
scales: {
  xAxes: [{
    type: 'time',
    time: {
      displayFormats: {hour: 'HH:mm'}
    }
  }]
 }
```

Comment: thanks mate - helped  a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
scales: {
  xAxes: [{
    type: 'time',
    time: {
      unit: 'minute',
      unitStepSize: 30,
      displayFormats: {
         'minute': this.person.Use24h ? 'HH:mm' : 'hh:mm A'
      }
    }
  }]
}
```

Comment: Does not appear to be working, maybe you could add a demo snippet.