# I want to add date which i fetch from database on X axis in ChartJS but It does not take the datetime value in it? Any Solution

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, datetime, charts

I want to add datetime on the X axis in ChartJs Graph. My date format is "02 Dec 2017 01:30 PM" but i cannot add it on X axis. I tried all the format but i does not accept any date format in ChartJs Graph. If you have any sample code, please share..

Comment: Can you convert the date to a number and then store the correct labels in an array? Then match the labels with the numbers for each tick.

Comment: can you send me some demos?

Comment: Not sure if this is possible. I did this using D3.js. Does this question help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37061945/how-to-format-x-axis-time-scale-values-in-chart-js-v2

Comment: I tried above code but it return always January 1st, 1970... Thank You..

Comment: Can you please share your code?

Comment: FInally done with custom tooltip...Thanks to all.

Comment: You should share your code and mark this as solved. Otherwise this question is useful to no one else.

Comment: I solved that issue.... Thanks you all